# What seems more accurate "You and your kid discover their true capability" or "You and your kid discover his/her true capability"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, pronouns, singular-they

I have been asked to look at some old admission response forms that our school mails back to applying students. This letter consists of their test scores and the programs that is offered to them.
Now, since we don't have an automated system that prints out a letter based on gender, the letter uses "his/her" > 50 times throughout the entire mail.

Since English isn't my first language - I don't know if it's grammatically accurate to replace them all with "their"?

Answer (score 0):

Given that ***you/your*** and ***they/their*** can all be singular or plural, It's no surprise that what I find in Google Books is...

> 1: [***You** and **your** child have **your...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22You%20and%20your%20child%20have%20your%22)

> 2: [***She** and **her** baby had **their...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22She%20and%20her%20baby%20had%20their%22)

...but I *don't* find anything for ***You** and **your** child have **their...*** It would be perfectly well understood, though, and it doesn't sound like an *outrageous* "mistake" to me.